# submenu is not display in frontpage in ITStuide (Ice theme) Joomla

Tags: joomla, submenu

I am working with IT Studio theme (Ice theme joomla) I am also add submenu in main menu but submenu is aren't display what is the problem ?
Here is my screenshots.

[Screenshots-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLfqS.png)

[Screenshots-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blF9O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is the setting "Show Sub Menus" in Module/Main Menu is set to "yes" ?
and what is the number of "End Level".

I think, you can try to add something like that in your css:

```
.menu li:hover ul {visibility:visible;}
```